# Why does this insert give error: There is a column named "column" in table "table", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to learn to use JDBC to make changes to a PostgreSQL database. I want to try inserting data into a table.

```sql
private static void createDatabase(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE my_table (Column1 Text)");
    stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (column1)");        
}
```

Running this, I get an error:

> ERROR: column "column1" does not exist
> Hint: There is a column named "column1" in table "my_table", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

If the column exists in the table, why am I getting an error?

Comment: If you try to insert values in the column `collumn1` which is of type text, you'll have to enclose the text to be inserted in single quotation marks. `"INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('some text for collumn1')"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your statement, `INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (Column1)`, is asking to insert (into `column1`) the current value of `column1`. Given the row does not exist yet, this cannot be done: there is no current value of `column1`. As an aside, it is a good practice to explicitly list the columns to insert to.

The `values` clause expects a list of values, expressions or parameters. For example, you can use:

```sql
INSERT INTO my_table (Column1) VALUES ('Value for Column1')
```